# Combine 10 columns of single-word data into 3 columns of max 4 words each, with punctuation

Tags: google-sheets, formula

PURPOSE: I am trying to combine 10 columns of names into three columns, following three guidelines. (I could probably work out the punctuation on my own if necessary, but don't know how to combine it with this task in one step.)

1. Add a parenthesis before the first word and after the last word, and commas in between names;
2. Add a maximum of four words into each column before going to next column (note the issue in number 3 below);
3. Ensure that a name is not broken between columns; this means a first-and-last cannot follow three names in a column, as that would mean five words. This break would have to happen after three words and begin the next column with the first-and-last (see rows 5 & 6 in the Desired Output, beginning "Evan" and "Frank").

**Here is an image of the example data:**
[image]

**Here is an image of the desired output:**
[image]

**Here is a link to the data:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rpZvxrBGPndRTmPq9ZXfOXm_XUbE23Uw0XabIqYnxqo/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(data,A2:O8,
       max_words,4,
       GET_COUNT,LAMBDA(str,COUNTA(SPLIT(str,", "))),
       first_last,REDUCE(TOROW(,1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/3,1,1,3),
                    LAMBDA(acc,i,HSTACK(acc,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(data,i,i+2),LAMBDA(names,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,names)))))),
       joined_first_last,BYROW(first_last,LAMBDA(names,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,names))),
       people,SPLIT(joined_first_last,", ",,),
       IFERROR(
         REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(people)),
           LAMBDA(v_acc,i,IFNA(VSTACK(v_acc,
             LET(ans,TOROW(
                       REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(INDEX(people,i))),
                         LAMBDA(h_acc,j,
                            IF(j=1,INDEX(people,i,j),         
                              IF(GET_COUNT(INDEX(people,i,j))+GET_COUNT(CHOOSECOLS(h_acc,-1))<=max_words,
                                h_acc&IF(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(h_acc))<COLUMNS(h_acc),,", "&INDEX(people,i,j)),
                                HSTACK(h_acc,INDEX(people,i,j)))))),3),
                 cols,COLUMNS(ans),
                 IF(cols=1,"("&ans&")",
                   IF(SEQUENCE(1,cols)=1,"("&ans&",",
                     IF(SEQUENCE(1,cols)=cols,ans&")",ans&",")))))))))))
```

[image]

The first part of the formula is transforming the data into a more usable format:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(data,A2:O8,
       max_words,4,
       GET_COUNT,LAMBDA(str,COUNTA(SPLIT(str,", "))),
       first_last,REDUCE(TOROW(,1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/3,1,1,3),
                    LAMBDA(acc,i,HSTACK(acc,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(data,i,i+1,i+2),LAMBDA(names,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,names)))))),
       joined_first_last,BYROW(first_last,LAMBDA(names,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,names))),
       people,SPLIT(joined_first_last,", ",,),
       people))
```

[image]

Then for each row we are iterating over each column and applying the following algorithm:

- If the count of the words in the current string plus the count of the words in the previous string is less than or equal to `*max_words*`,  append the current string to the previous string, else;
- (If the count of the words in the current string plus the count of the words in the previous string is greater than `*max_words*`) create a new string.

```cpp
// if the count of the words in the current string plus the count of the words in the previous string is less than or equal to `max_words`

IF(GET_COUNT(INDEX(people,i,j))+GET_COUNT(CHOOSECOLS(h_acc,-1))<=max_words,

// append the current string to the previous string

   h_acc&IF(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(h_acc))<COLUMNS(h_acc),,", "&INDEX(people,i,j)),

// otherwise, create a new string

   HSTACK(h_acc,INDEX(people,i,j))))
```

Comment: This is gold!! I do have two questions: 1) I am having trouble making this work for all rows of a data set that may be large or small. I want it to work for all rows with data, of an unknown number. 2) I need to ignore data in the middle column of each data set. For example any data in B should be skipped, also E, H, K, N, etc. . —Is this possible?

Comment: Also, sorry, 3) I did not show this in my data set and I should have — some of my actual rows contain no data. Right now the blank rows throw an error.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in the sample sheet? Also please update the sharing settings to Anyone with the link -> EDITOR.

Comment: I have done so. The sheet allows EDITOR, and I have updated it to contain the two issues that throw errors.

Comment: Thank you! I would love to offer you $20 for this help - maybe to buy a cup of coffee and a scone next time you are coding. I could PayPal it to an email or send you a redemption code. I can be reached at larger-enamel0w@icloud.com —I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user1132149, thanks! I have a donation link in my [about me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17887301/z) section.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the code below, which was suggested by Z and edited by him according to the comments above. It works great and I am very grateful!!

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(data,A2:O8,
       max_words,4,
       GET_COUNT,LAMBDA(str,COUNTA(SPLIT(str,", "))),
       first_last,REDUCE(TOROW(,1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/3,1,1,3),
                    LAMBDA(acc,i,HSTACK(acc,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(data,i,i+2),LAMBDA(names,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,names)))))),
       joined_first_last,BYROW(first_last,LAMBDA(names,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,names))),
       people,SPLIT(joined_first_last,", ",,),
       IFERROR(
         REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(people)),
           LAMBDA(v_acc,i,IFNA(VSTACK(v_acc,
             LET(ans,TOROW(
                       REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(INDEX(people,i))),
                         LAMBDA(h_acc,j,
                            IF(j=1,INDEX(people,i,j),         
                              IF(GET_COUNT(INDEX(people,i,j))+GET_COUNT(CHOOSECOLS(h_acc,-1))<=max_words,
                                h_acc&IF(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(h_acc))<COLUMNS(h_acc),,", "&INDEX(people,i,j)),
                                HSTACK(h_acc,INDEX(people,i,j)))))),3),
                 cols,COLUMNS(ans),
                 IF(cols=1,"("&ans&")",
                   IF(SEQUENCE(1,cols)=1,"("&ans&",",
                     IF(SEQUENCE(1,cols)=cols,ans&")",ans&",")))))))))))
```